# Office 365 Exchange Management Shell - Use data from Excel to run a loop with command

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

We are having round about 400 users that use Office 365 E-Mail Exchange which is managed on a local server via the Exchange Management Console. We activated E-Mail archives for the users that had PST-Files left on the server and migrated them by hand. To activate the mailbox archive we used the following command :

```
enable-remotemailbox <username> -archive
```

That worked fine and all. Now we want to double check and activate the archive for every user that has not been activated by hand. For this we have an excel sheet of all users with usernames which we want to run in a loop - so my question is :

Is it possible to tell the powershell to take information form an Excel/CSV file and loop through it with the above command (if an error occurs it needs to ignore and still run through). I imagined it somehow like

```
$users = Import-CSV C:\users.csv | foreach $user in $users
enable-remotemailbox $user -archive
```

Is it possible in this way or even an easier way?

Comment: Don't pipe it. Try with an new line. The rest of the code looks like it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Lets consider your CSV looks like this:

```
User
Alice
Bob
```

Then you can import the CSV and loop over each user using:

```
Import-Csv C:\users.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    enable-remotemailbox $_.User -archive
}
```